# Does $M$-injectivity impy injectivity?

Tags: modules, projective-module, injective-module

Let $N,M\in R$-mod. We say that $N$ is **$M$-injective** if for any $L$ submodule of $M$ and any homomorphism $f:L\rightarrow N$ exists a homomorphism $g\colon M\rightarrow N$ that extends $f$.

In the other hand, $N$ is an **injective** module if for any two $A,B\in R$-mod such that $A\subseteq B$ and $f\in \text{Hom}_R(A,N)$ there exists an element $g\in \text{Hom}_R(B,N)$ that extends $f$.

Am I right that "Every injective module is just a $B$-injective module? Or, am I losing a subtle detail?

Comment: What's $B{}{}$?

Comment: is an arbitrary $R$-mód that contains $A$.

Comment: What's $A{}{}$?

Comment: Both $A,B$ are arbitrary $R$-modules.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$N$ is injective iff it is $M$-injective for **all** modules $M$.

But it's a theorem (Baer's criterion) that $N$ is injective iff it is $R$-injective.